# Regex to match a string only at the beginning of the text

Tags: python, regex

I only want to match `change://problem/` at the beginning of the `change_title`,not after that ,can someone provide guidance on how to fix this regex ?

```
import re
change_title = ' <change://problem/62678646> [Cloned from other]: test change information data change://problem/59442345 with lots of AP data'
changelist = re.findall(".*?\s*\S*(?:change:\/\/(?:problem\/)?)(\d{8})", change_title)
print('changelist %s'%changelist)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
changelist ['62678646', '59442345']
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
changelist ['62678646']
```

Comment: Use `re.search` to get the first match from a string.

Comment: Try this `"[^\<]*?(?:change:\/\/(?:problem\/)?)(\d{8})"`

Comment: @hacker315 - that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
change_title = ' <change://problem/62678646> [Cloned from other]: test change information data change://problem/59442345 with lots of AP data'
changelist = re.findall("change://problem/(\d{8})>", change_title)
print('changelist %s'%changelist)
```

You can verify the result here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

The Regex can be made even shorter:

```
changelist = re.findall(".+(\d{8})>", change_title)
```